# Why would someone want a 15" vacuum sealer over a 12"?

Tags: food-safety, food-preservation, sous-vide

I am looking at a vacuum sealer. It seems pretty typical with a 12" seal bar. This is a Foodsaver type, and not a vacuum chamber. However, for a few more dollars (there's a sale) I can get a larger one with a 15" seal bar.

I'm not even sure if people regularly seal with bags 15" wide. I'm assuming those bags would be pricier too. I don't expect to be sealing long fish or ribs or anything with any regularity, and if I did, I could just seal them long-ways instead of width-ways.

**Why would I want a 15" vacuum sealer over a 12"?**

If this post is considered too subjective, just ignore whether "I" need one, and share with me why someone would want one.

Comment: If you don't want your post to be subjective, you should ask about the pros and cons of a 15" sealer vs a 12" one.

Answer (score 3):

95% of the time, a 12" meets my needs. But when I want to make pork belly bacon, most slabs don't fit in the 11"-wide bags without folding. 15" handles briskets and pork bellies easier. Of course, I have to make a lot of pastrami, corned beef, and bacon to justify the price.

Answer (score 1):

Versatility? If I wanted to seal a larger roast to freeze/sous vide, having the extra 3" would be handy. A larger unit, could still seal smaller bags, but assuming you have the space to store it, it gives you more choices?

Comment: Yes I suppose so. But the only time this would be needed is it you are sealing an item that has 15" as its shortest dimension, which is hard for me to imagine in regular use.

Comment: 15" sealer means you're looking at a 30" circumference for the item... so um... average 10" diameter? I could easily see a prime rib roast hitting those dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

At least of the models I have seen, there is more to the 15 inch units than just that they are wider.  The bags are also more expensive.  They are heavier duty with the bags intended to hold up longing in use to potentially store items longer.  Many in fact are labeled as Game Savers.

So, along with the option to use on larger items as mentioned, many of these units are also at least promoted as heavier duty type use.  Not necessarily using it more, but using it with the likelihood you expect to store the item for more than a couple of months.  I think on the associated bags the company claims 5x the storage time which is likely a stretch, but goes to their intent.

Comment: The models are identical, except one is 15". I do get your meaning, though.